# (Unity prefab) проблема с клонированием

Tags: unity3d, prefabs

У меня есть префаб и словарь для записи в его дочерние элементы значений

```
 public GameObject element;
 Dictionary<string, string> dtData;
```

Сам префаб представляет собой длинный `gameodject`, в который вложены некоторое количество вложенных `inputfields` -  все вместе одна строка в прокручиваемом списке. Добавляю новый префаб  - создается новая строка, ну и так до бесконечности. В итоге имею прокручиваемый список. Все префабы вложены в `content`.

Есть метод, который добавляет на сцену префаб после клика по кнопке и заполняет его потомков новыми данными (данные получаются из другого класса после парсинга XML файла):

```
public void LoadData() {
            //проверяю, пуст ли словарь
            Debug.Log(dtData.Count);

            XmlDocument docXml = new XmlDocument();
            docXml.Load(userPath);
            //создаю экземпляр префаба и помещаю его в контейнер
            GameObject elementForDT = Instantiate(element);
            elementForDT.transform.SetParent(content.transform, false);

            //передаю данные о документе xml в другой класс, который извлекает из документа значения нужных узлов и записывает в массив (метод GetDTData())
                parseDTNew = new ParseDTNew

                {
                    DocXml = docXml
                };
                parseDTNew.GetDTData();

                //переменная для ссылки на словарь + добавляю значение номера по порядку
                dtData = parseDTNew.DtData;
                dtData.Add("numberElement", number.ToString());
                //перебираю словарь, чтобы записать в префаб данные из словаря
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValue in dtData)
                {

                    string childName = keyValue.Key;


                    for (int i = 0; i < element.transform.childCount; i++)
                    {

                        GameObject child = element.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
                        //если они есть
                        if (child != null)
                        {
                            //и их имена совпадают с ключом
                            if (child.name == childName)
                            {
                                child.GetComponent<InputField>().text = keyValue.Value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //  Debug.Log(keyValue.Key + " " + keyValue.Value);
                }
                number++;

}
```

В итоге после клика по кнопк ея получаю префаб, т.е. одну строку в списке, но со значениями после парсинга из прошлого  клика (префаба), а при повторном клике создается новый экземпляр с уже актуальными значениями. Т.е. нужно два раза кликнуть, чтобы получить экземпляр префаба с нужными данными (ну и первый удалить после этого, т.к. он хранит неверные данные). Понимаю, что где-то что-то нужно очистить, но все попытки (включая применения метода destroy, чтобы разрушить потомков, а также очистку текста потомков при создании нового экземпляра перфаба) не увенчались успехом. Сам словарь чист перед каждым новым кликом, т.к. поставила на проверку его длину (в самом начале метода), и каждый раз длина массива равна нулю. В общем, не знаю, как решить проблему, подскажите, что делаю ни так?!

Comment: GameObject child = element.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;

тут вы работаете с префабом, а не с его экземпляром?

Comment: просто странно  что вы берете не детей контента,  не детей экземпляра префаба, а именно самого префаба . Или может я что то не так понял

Comment: @Andrey действительно, забыла исправить в этом месте. Спасибо)